# Select everything where key=value in Firebase and Angular Fire

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, firebase, angularfire

I have a firebase database that looks like this:

[image: Firebase Database Example]

I have the `courseID` variable stored in my `$state.params.courseID` parameter, and now I want to only pull `Sections` where the `coursedID` matches the `$state.params.courseID` variable, and then store the results in an array here is what I tried so far:

```
    var sectionsRef = firebase.child('Sections');
    sectionsRef
    .orderByChild('courseID')
    .on('value', function(snap) {
      console.log(snap.val(), 'Sections');
      console.log(snap.key(), 'Key');
    });
    $scope.sections = $firebaseArray(sectionsRef);
```

I'm really confused on how to do even basic queries like this in Firebase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use the `equalTo()` method in combination with `orderByChild()`.**

```
var sectionsRef = firebase.child('Sections');
sectionsRef
.orderByChild('courseID')
.equalTo('And now?');
$scope.sections = $firebaseArray(sectionsRef);
```

If you want to be slick with your routing, you can create a factory that retrieves the courses by `courseID` and resolve it in the router.

```
angular.module('app', ['firebase'])
  .config(ApplicationConfig)
  .constant('FBURL', 'https://<my-fb-app>.firebaseio.com/')
  .service('RootRef', ['FBURL', Firebase)
  .factory('Sections', Sections)
  .controller('SectionsCtrl', SectionsCtrl);

function Sections(RootRef, $firebaseArray) {
  var sectionRef = RootRef.child('sections');
  return {
    byCourseId: function byCourseId(value) {
      sectionsRef
        .orderByChild('courseID')
        .equalTo(value);
      return $firebaseArray(sectionsRef);
    }
  }
}

function ApplicationConfig($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state("sections", {
      controller: "SectionsCtrl",
      templateUrl: "views/sections.html",
      resolve: {
        sections: function(Sections, $state) {
          return Sections.byCourseId($state.params.courseid);
        }
      }
    });
}

function SectionsCtrl($scope, sections) {
   // This is the resolved data in your controller
   $scope.sections = sections;
}
```

Comment: Ok that worked, I stored the variable in the snapshot like this:
`$scope.sections = snap.val();`
How would I access the snapshot id value like Firebase provides in the `$firebaseArray()` method?

Comment: You don't need to store anything in the `on` method. Just passing the ref to `$firebaseArray()` will keep the array synchronized for you. I update the answer to show how you can inject the desired courses into the controller with the `resolve()` method.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be keeping the array synchronized, it just dumps all of the data into the scope variable, but if I assign the scope variable to the snap.val() it exports the correct data, it just doesn't pass through the id of the section anywhere (firebaseArray puts it in the $id)

Comment: Nevermind, I had to change the way I was accessing the variable like this:
`var sectionsRef =
        firebase.child('Sections')
        .orderByChild('courseID')
        .equalTo($state.params.courseID);`
Thanks for the help, that makes a lot more sense

Comment: No problem! `The $firebaseArray()` takes in the ref and then binds an array to all of the Firebase child events. So you don't need to call `on` because it's done for you.

Comment: This worked but caused another problem, now I can't order the results by priority, see the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33992935/how-to-get-specific-element-and-orderby-priority-in-firebase-and-angular