# How to get specific element and orderby priority in Firebase and Angular

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have a firebase reference like this:

```
$scope.lessons = $firebaseArray(firebase.child('Lessons').orderByChild('courseID').equalTo($state.params.courseID));
```

I'm outputting the lessons like this:

```
<ul>
        <li class="lesson" ng-if="lesson.moduleID == module.$id" ng-repeat="lesson in lessons" lessonid="{{lesson.$id}}">
            <lessonedit></lessonedit>
        </li>
</ul>
```

I need to order the lessons by priority, but when I add the orderByPriority() function to the end of the firebase reference it says I can only use one orderBy call.

I tried the filter `lesson in lessons | orderByPriority` but it says that filter does not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Priority` is an attribute of lesson, you can use the angular filter [`orderBy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="lesson" 
        ng-if="lesson.moduleID == module.$id" 
        ng-repeat="lesson in lessons | orderBy:'Priority'" 
        lessonid="{{lesson.$id}}">
        <lessonedit></lessonedit>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's not an attribute unfortunately, priority is built into Firebase, they have functions to update the priority, but in this case it's of no use because you can't order by it.

Comment: I eventually had to add a priority attribute in order to get this to work.

Comment: How much data are you pulling down with this? If it's a small amount then this is a fine solution. But this won't scale with larger data sets.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you can't mix `.orderByPriority()` and `.orderByChild()` as they are different order by functions.

However, you can still solve your problem by only using `.orderByPriority()`, if you re-structure your data.

[Structuring your data a specific way allows you query your data, as if you could use two orderBy functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33976380/how-to-do-order-by-query-using-firebase/33986508#33986508).

In your case you have a location of "Lessons" that all have a push-id key of their "lesson id": `/lessons/$lessonID`.

You could change your structure to key off of the `courseId` and *then* the `lesson_id`: `/lessions/$courseID/$lessonID`.

The data would look like this:

```
{
  "lessons": {
    "1": {
      "-K4NQTsjo3iswX4PhKUw": {
        title: "My Course"
      },
      "-K4NAWsjo5iswX4Jk4fa": {
        title: "Another Course"
      }
    }
    "2": {
      "-K4NQTsjo3iswX4PhKUw": {
        title: "My Course"
      },
      "-K4NQPjMZVCoFRYc_1v5": {
        title: "Intro to Data Structure"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now since the key uses the `courseID`, we can order by by both `courseID` and priority:

```
var courseID = $state.params.courseID;
var ref = new Firebase('<my-firebase-app>.firebaseio.com/lessons');
var query = ref.child(courseID).orderByPriority();
var syncArray = $firebaseArray(query);
```

You can store this in a factory in your AngularJS code.

```
angular.module('app', ['firebase')
  .constant('FirebaseUrl', '<my-firebase-app>')
  .service('RootRef', ['FirebaseUrl', Firebase])
  .factory('Lessons', Lessons)
  .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

function Lessons(RootRef) {
  return function Lessons(courseID) {
    var ref = RootRef.child('Lessons');
    var query = ref.child(courseID).orderByPriority();
    return $firebaseArray(query);
  }
}

function MainCtrl($scope, $state, Lessons) {
  var courseID = $state.params.courseID;
  $scope.lessons = Lessons(courseID);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to create lessons with a sequential ID like this?

Comment: Not natively with Firebase. Sequential/index based IDs are a poor fit with realtime data. When the ID is just a number it can easily collide when indexes change. Push IDs are unique which helps avoid any collisions and or race conditions.

Comment: Then i'm stuck using push id's and I can't change the structure.  I added a new field called `priority` to the item and I can orderBy that, it's too bad because I can't use any of Firebases built in set priority or orderby priority methods, but it works this way without too much hassle.

Comment: You can always migrate to push-ids by updating the sequential ids. If my answer works please mark it as accepted to keep the unanswered queue clean.

Answer (score 0):

Using Firebase's new Query API, you can do this with:

var ref = new Firebase('https://your.firebaseio.com/');

```
ref
  .orderBy('genre')
  .startAt('comedy').endAt('comedy')
  .orderBy('lead')
  .startAt('Jack Nicholson').endAt('Jack Nicholson')
  .on('value', function(snapshot) { 
  console.log(snapshot.val()); 
  });
```

Note that the new Query API is still in beta, so things may change before it's officially released.

See this [jsbin for a similar query on Firebase's sample data set](http://jsbin.com/deboqi/1/edit?js,console).

You can check the original Post of Frank van Puffelen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase)

Comment: Firebase queries are not in beta, they have been available since 11-04-14. https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-11-04-firebase-realtime-queries.html